# Error function bindParam() on a non-object during submitting a form

Tags: php, object, pdo, fatal-error

I have a problem got me a headache from yesterday is that when I want to submit a form with php it shows me that error Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object

and that the code of it : [image: Hours.php file]

And that's the config File  :[image: config.php File]:

Comment: Please look at the right pane. Notice **dozens** of questions on the exactly the same error? --->

Comment: Which answers you tried?

Comment: What certain answer you tried?

Answer (score 1):

It means that `prepare` returned `false` because of an error. Set

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: DON'T wrap in try catch. it is useless, inflexible and insecure

Comment: Who said "stay in the dark"?

Comment: It's better to catch an exception in controlled way so you can see the error message. Doesn't mean it has to stay that way for production. Although I don't see why that would harm.

Comment: You can see an error message without a catch all right. Makes try..catch useless and bloating your code for no reason

Comment: The error is not during connection but in `prepare`. Most likely not matching column count/names.

Comment: I already explained. What is happening is that `$db->prepare` returns false because of an error. If it's not column count/name mismatch, than something else. Consult the documentation on PDO error handling http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php. The error is logged, set in a PHP variable or in an exception.

Answer (score -1):

**1.** Store your SQL query in a variable ($sql)

```
$ins = $db->prepare($sql);
```

**2.** Create variables for your `$_POST`'s

**3.** Replace your :mu etc in SQL code with ? placeholders

**4.** Bind param expects a data type and then the data - for example

```
    $ins = $db->prepare($sql);
    :m = htmlentities($_POST['m1'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    ...
    :su = htmlentities($_POST['su1'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $ins->bind_param('sssssss', :m, :tu, :w, :th, :f, :sa, :su);
    $ins->execute();
```

Comment: This is just a fantastic answer.